# Is it possible for an Applescript to dim/up 0%/100% screen brightness on OSX 10.9 Mavericks when connected to external display?

Tags: macos, applescript

Previously, this could be done with an Applescript on Mountain Lion. This is because it targets System Preferences to adjust the brightness. System Preferences no longer has this setting in OSX 10.9 Mavericks. Any guidance on this issue would be appreciated. Thanks.[image: brightness external display]

Correction, my projector is plugged in all of the time so when the script is run, it jumps to the "projector" pane instead of the "built-in display" pane where the slider is located.
I was thinking something like this would target the "Built-in Display" pane that has the slider. I can't seem to get it to work though.

```
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id         "com.apple.preference.displays"
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to         tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
            delay 1
            set value of slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of         process "System Preferences" to 0

        end tell
        quit
    end tell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still there?.

[image]

The old Applescripts I found will not work any more.

One example

```
tell application "System Preferences" 
    activate 
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.displays" 
    tell application "System Events" 
        delay 1 
        set value of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences" to 0.5 
        delay 1 
    end tell 
    quit 
end tell
```

There is no *group 2 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System*

A simple fix change it to :*group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System*

Working on Macbook 10.9:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 1
        set value of slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences" to 0.5

    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

Update*

You can use the name of your window: "Built-in Display"
Change the line:

```
set value of slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences" to 0.5
```

to

```
set value of slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Built-in Display" of process "System Preferences" to 0.5
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the slider window. I only use my Mac when it is connected to a projector and that display page doesn't have it. I need this script in order to automatically dim and un dim screen brightness when my projector is connected/disconnected. The script that you posted works fine only when the Macbook pro is not connected to an external display. It opens System Preferences with my "projector" window on top of the "Built-in display" window that has the slider on it when it is connected. Any Ideas on how to target the "Built-in display" window?

Comment: You can use the name of your window: "Built-in Display" . See my update

Answer (score 6):

You might also use [brightness.c](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/):

```
brightness 1 # set the brightness to the maximum on all displays
brightness -d 0 0.5 # set the brightness to 50% on the first display
```

If others search for how to put displays to sleep, you can use `pmset displaysleepnow` in 10.9 and later:

```
do shell script "pmset displaysleepnow"
```

Comment: `pmset displaysleepnow` sorted me, Darwin 13.4.0 -- enjoy your upvote

Comment: Code for brightness.c at: https://web.archive.org/web/20130802162107/http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/

Comment: For anyone still researching how to change the brightness (quickly and without GUI scripting), this code is available as a command from GitHub [here](https://github.com/nriley/brightness). It's also been updated for M1 Macs and macOS Big Sur. Here's how to install it: First [install Homebrew](https://brew.sh) in the Terminal if it's not already installed, then install the brightness application by typing in `brew install brightness`. Running it from AppleScript can be done by writing `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/brightness 0.5"`.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone is still looking for help on this issue. It is possible to adjust BOTH the display of a MacBook Pro and the thunderbolt display from the same keyboard. For the MacBook Display you use the well known 2 keys with a small and a big sun symbol - on my MacBook Pro these are F1 and F2  . For the thunderbolt display you can use those keys too provided you also press ctrl + cmd.
By the way when you press F1 and F2 together with alt-key the system control for monitors show up

Comment: Thanks that's just what I was looking for. `Ctrl + Cmd + F1/F2` didn't work for me, but `Ctrl + F1/F2` did.